# How can I make a screenshot from background of a textview?

Tags: android

How can I make a **screenshot** from a textview  background? in **JPEG**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the view to draw itself on a canvas. That's probably the simplest method.

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetView.getWidth(),
                   targetView.getHeight(),
                   Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
targetView.draw(c);
```

See http://arpitonline.com/blog/2012/07/17/capturing-bitmaps-of-views-in-android/